# Google Drive API uploading files

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to figure the google drive api (node.js) out for a client. I need to upload files to their drive. I've decided to use a service account and have the auth working. I'm trying to upload a sample file but I can't find it in my drive. My guess is I need to somehow link it to my drive, but I'm not sure. Here is the code I have based off of an example I found online:

```
async function upload(){
const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: authorize()
});

const res = await drive.files.create({
    requestBody: {
        name: 'Test',
        mimeType: 'text/plain'
    },
    media: {
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
        body: 'Hello World'
    }
}, function (err, file) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
    }
});
```

authorize() returns the jwtclient and works fine.

console.log(res) returns file id undefined.

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

When the response value is retrieved from googleapis for Node.js, please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
```

#### To:

```
console.log('File Id: ', file.data.id);
```

#### Note:

- In your script, I think that you can also use the following script.

  ```
    const res = await drive.files
      .create({
        requestBody: {
          name: "Test",
          mimeType: "text/plain",
        },
        media: {
          mimeType: "text/plain",
          body: "Hello World",
        }
      })
      .catch(console.log);
    if (res) console.log("File Id: ", res.data.id);
  ```

#### Reference:

- [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)